# How do we move a working directory to a different location?

Tags: command-line, mv

I am trying to move the files of my already installed Ipython to a new destination folder.
I have used the following command and I get the error, can someone help:

```
asudipta@asudipta-Inspiron-1525:~/Desktop$ sudo mv ipython-2.1.0~/Documents/ipython-2.1.0
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘ipython-2.1.0~/Documents/ipython-2.1.0’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move `ipython-2.1.0` to `~/Documents/ipython-2.1.0` run:

```
mv ipython-2.1.0 ~/Documents/ipython-2.1.0
```

Your command was missing a space between ipython-2.1.0 and ~/Documents/ipython-2.1.0.

Comment: You also don't need sudo for files in your home directory.

Comment: Yeah, if you're moving a files/folders that are yours to begin with, don't use sudo. Will just cause permissions issues.